# redirect and change url from html to none html htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect domain.com/abcdef.html to domain.com/abcdef and the new url´s content should be domain.com/abcdef.html.

I realy struggle here. I can achieve to get the content from the html shown without having the html in the url, but then both urls are available.

When I try to achieve both I get an endlessloop and an ERR 500, but I have no clue how I can prevent this endlessloop.

so my try one - making both urls available with the same content looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

The second rule is just the same withtout the first two lines:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

resulting into an endless loop. My research only brought me to solutions for either one or for a try with the index.php. But I search for a htaccess-only solution.

Is it possible?

**EDIT:** I understand why the endlessloop happens
I request blabla.html --> rule 1 makes it to blabla and requests again, rule 2 makes it to blabla.html requests again and so on. But how can I prevent this?

**EDIT 2:** So I tried as suggested by starkeen, and had this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

which still lead to the endlessloop. Using it with the RewriteCond still has both available (blabla.com/content.html and blabla.com/content)

Unfortunately it is not apache 2.4 so I couldnt try the END tag, but I try to reach my hoster and ask them if I they update it.

Or did I get you wrong and mix something up with the htaccess?

**EDIT 3:** So since my code should work, but doesnt, here the whole htaccess to make sure there isn´t anything else that blocks the **** from working.

```
AuthName "nottellingyou" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/www/top/secret/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the loop error, put the following rule bellow **RewriteEngine On**  line

```
RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This terminates internal rewrite processing on 2nd iteration so /file.html will not get rewritten to the same path again.

On apach 2.4 you can use END flag in your RewriteRule to prevent the internal loop

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+) $1.html [END]
```

To remove the .html extension, you can also use this script :

```
RewriteEngine on


#1)redirect /file.html to /file

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]
 #2)check if /file exists as an .html ,if it exists ,rewrite /file to /file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f

RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, but unfortunately it wouldnt work for me! Could you please check my edit if i did it right?

Comment: @marcel you are not using the rule correctly. It should be bellow RewriteEngine on line.

Comment: thanks alot, I misread it as before RewriteEnginge somehow. But unfortunately same effect. (editedhow is now looks like --> leads to loop for me)

Comment: yep, I tried inkognito mode and refresh with open developer tools and disabled cache. It also switched from wroking to not working which should mean that it was without cache

Comment: Wired. This code works fine on my server. Do you have any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: I will edit my post in a second, to show you the full thing (theres a bit of wordpress in it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135044/discussion-between-marcel-schmid-and-starkeen).

Comment: @MarcelSchmid I have added a new solution. see the edit.

Comment: awesome, I would like to give you a cookie! :D thanks for all you effort, this finally does the magic!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a website with URLs like magepow.com/hello-world.html 1 and if you want to redirect that to magepow.com/hello-world/, then you can try the below code. Copy/paste this into your .htaccess file. Make sure you replace magepow.com 1 with your own URL.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+).html$ http://magepow.com/$1
```

This should work fine, and if your website has ‘HTTPS’ instead of ‘HTTP’, do change that as well.

Note: If the above code is not working for your website, you can try these instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/.]+).html$ /$1/$2/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+).html$ /$1/$2/$3/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+).html$ /$1/$2/$3/$4/
```